# Python Flask time out? FLASK + NGINX + uWSGI

Tags: python, mysql, nginx, uwsgi, raspbian

As usual, i have another very weird issue. I have a NGINX webserver that is accessible from anywhere.It is serving my python file with the help of uWSGI. Within the python file i make use of the mysql-connector library to get information from a mysql database that is running on the same machine. (The machine is a raspberry pi running raspbian). I have an index page that just returns a string and a /resources page that connects with the database and returns some information in json.

After give or take 15 minutes everything breaks down. The server becomes unesponsive and shows the 'Bad gateway' error or the 'a time out occured' error. I restarted just the uWSGI to narrow down the cause and doing so brings my app back online again. This means it's either that or my flask server somehow.

I used the following link: I used the following link: http://vladikk.com/2013/09/12/serving-flask-with-nginx-on-ubuntu/

I find it VERY difficult to find information about this. 
What could it be? How could i troubleshoot this? What are possible fixes?

UWSGI Logfiles

clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 4
current working directory: /home/pi
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager** 
your processes number limit is 7336
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 65536
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /var/www/demoapp/demoapp_uwsgi.sock fd 3
Python version: 2.7.9 (default, Sep 17 2016, 20:55:23)  [GCC 4.9.2]
Set PythonHome to /var/www/demoapp/venv
 **Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads** 
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x67b490
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 64256 bytes (62 KB) for 1 cores
 **Operational MODE: single process** 
added /var/www/demoapp/ to pythonpath.
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x67b490 pid: 32459 (default app)
 **uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 32459, cores: 1)

Comment: Mmmm... Interesting. How many uWSGI workers or threads do you have running? You should have at least 3 workers. Also, is there any information in the log files (NGINX, uWSGI, flask)?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. I have added the last couple rows of the log files. It appears i just have 1 worker. How come 1 worker blocks so quickly though? And how do I add more?

Comment: One worker will block because usually, you'll have a worker accepting requests and one performing I/O operations, viz reading from a database in your case. Because you only have one worker, this becomes problematic. See the [docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html) for some tips (you may search for `processes` on this page). You can increase the number of workers by using the `-p num` option from the command line, or `processes = num` from a configuration file (num is the integer number of processes you want). Let me know if you need additional clarification.

Comment: Thanks a lot Keenan! It seems to have fixed the issue!

Comment: Hi Keenan, actually, the problem is back. The performance has increased but the server still times out after 15 / 30 minutes...

Comment: Also, it seems this is only the case with the URL's that use a connection with the database. The index page ramains available but the query's that get data from the database result in a 'Gateway Time-out error'.

Comment: That's not good :( Anything in the log files? P.S I don't know if you can reject an accepted answer, but you're more than welcomed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a worker blocking issue.

One worker will block because usually, you'll have a worker accepting requests and one performing I/O operations, viz reading from a database in your case. Because you only have one worker, this becomes problematic.

See the [docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html) for some tips (you may search for `processes` on this page). You can increase the number of workers by using the `-p num` option from the command line, or `processes = num` from a configuration file (num is the integer number of processes you want).